# Is pretty nice nicer than nice?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

The terms *"pretty nice"* and *"nice"* can perhaps not be compared in regards to nicety.

I find *"pretty nice"* to be a more *informal* way of relaying that something is rather awesome.

In one way the adverb (?) in this example also tune the somewhat ecstatic adjective down a bit. At the same time I notice the use of, for example, *"pretty nice"* when it looks like the person intend to say *"very nice"* – which in turn is *not* to tune down. Can one perhaps say that *"pretty nice"* in general means *"very nice"*? (Thus nicer the nice. :P)

Comment: The word pretty made me confused once before and I asked about it on this website.Check it out. http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41285/the-usage-of-the-word-pretty-is-pretty-confusing/61709

Comment: @Mrt: That is a pretty nice question ...

Comment: [This site](http://www.seadict.com/en/en/pretty) lists *rather, somewhat, fairly, reasonably, moderately, comparatively, relatively, tolerably, passably, adequately, satisfactorily, decently, respectably;* informal *kind of, sort of* as "synonyms" for ***pretty***. It's entirely a matter of opinion (and exact context) whether ***quite** pretty* emphasizes or downplays the degree of prettiness being referred to (or indeed, is just a meaningless "noise word" idiomatically thrown in).

Comment: OK. A dilemma here. Can I accept an answer as well as click on *"That solved my problem!"*?

Comment: As it now is marked duplicate I  guess I can accept as well as it being properly linked to dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is probably colloquial.  In our family, yes, the term "pretty - anything", was meant to intensify the meaning of whatever the "anything" was.  So, yes, "Pretty nice", or "pretty good" does in fact convey (to us) an escalation of 'awesomeness'.   What we are saying is that it is exemplary!

This use of "pretty" as a quantifier, or intensifier, is not uniformly understood, at least around here.  (SE U.S.) Its use is, as you pointed out, informal, and as I have explained, perhaps regional.